# How to convert guid to *char

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to convert a CLSID to a *char in c++ so I can display it in a text box. I am new to c++ so please make this as simple a s possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C'ish solution:

```
/* 128 bit GUID to human-readable string */
char * guid_to_str(const GUID * id, char * out) {
    int i;
    char * ret = out;
    out += sprintf(out, "%.8lX-%.4hX-%.4hX-", id->Data1, id->Data2, id->Data3);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(id->Data4); ++i) {
        out += sprintf(out, "%.2hhX", id->Data4[i]);
        if (i == 1) *(out++) = '-';
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This assumes the output buffer has been already allocated, and should be of a size of 37 bytes (including the null terminating character).

The output is of the form `"75B22630-668E-11CF-A6D9-00AA0062CE6C"`

**Usage example:**

```
GUID g;
char buffer[37];

std::cout << guid_to_str(&g, buffer);
```

**Note:**

This code exists because I had to implement GUID parsing under Linux, otherwise I would have used the Windows API function `StringFromCLSID` mentioned by @krowe.

Comment: Thank you all I can give you is +1 and tick

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140722102235/http://blog.tomaka17.com/2012/09/c-converting-guid-to-string-and-vice-versa/) is a great example for converting GUID to string and vice versa that I am using in my projects:

```
std::string guidToString(GUID guid) {
    std::array<char,40> output;
    snprintf(output.data(), output.size(), "{%08X-%04hX-%04hX-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X}", guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3], guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);
    return std::string(output.data());
}

GUID stringToGUID(const std::string& guid) {
    GUID output;
    const auto ret = sscanf(guid.c_str(), "{%8X-%4hX-%4hX-%2hX%2hX-%2hX%2hX%2hX%2hX%2hX%2hX}", &output.Data1, &output.Data2, &output.Data3, &output.Data4[0], &output.Data4[1], &output.Data4[2], &output.Data4[3], &output.Data4[4], &output.Data4[5], &output.Data4[6], &output.Data4[7]);
    if (ret != 11)
        throw std::logic_error("Unvalid GUID, format should be {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}");
    return output;
}
```

In the example, it firsts uses **char*** before converting to string so this is exactly what you are looking for in an efficient way.

Comment: great job, Tanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683917%28VS.85%29.aspx) has a function for this:

```
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID ((OLESTR "Adobe.SVGCtl.3"),&clsid);

// Get class id as string
LPOLESTR className;
hr = StringFromCLSID(clsid, &className);

// convert to CString
CString c = (char *) (_bstr_t) className;

// then release the memory used by the class name
CoTaskMemFree(className);

// Now c is ready to use
```

Comment: Can you Give usage example?

Answer (score 1):

A CLSID is the same as a UUID, so you can use the **UuidToString()** function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379352(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What's the relationship with RPC?